# Display text depending on what sound is playing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So, I'd like to be able to have text appear that would tell me what sound is playing when I press the button, but I don't really even know where to start with that.

My HTML is the button you press

My JavaScript randomizes the sound that will be played

Any help would be appreciated

```
<a href="#" id="soundbutton" class="button button1"></a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="meme.js"></script>
```

---

```
var sounds = ["Titanic.mp3",
"Legitness.mp3",
"Lying.mp3",
"Lebron.mp3",
"Yeahboy.mp3",
"Rocketlauncher.mp3",
"Billnye.mp3",
"Running.mp3",
"Donethis.mp3"
];
var sound;
function generateRandomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
function playSound() {
  var x = generateRandomNumber(sounds.length - 1);
  var soundSrc = sounds[x];
  if (sound) {
      sound.pause();
  } else {
      sound = new Audio();
  }
  sound.src = soundSrc;
  sound.play();
}
document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```

Answer (score 2):

`soundSrc` will tell you what sound you're playing. In my example in the `playSound()` function, I'm just setting the `.innerHTML` of some element that shows the status to `soundSrc`.

```js
var sounds = [
    "Titanic.mp3",
    "Legitness.mp3",
    "Lying.mp3",
    "Lebron.mp3",
    "Yeahboy.mp3",
    "Rocketlauncher.mp3",
    "Billnye.mp3",
    "Running.mp3",
    "Donethis.mp3"
];

var sound;

function generateRandomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function playSound() {
    var x = generateRandomNumber(sounds.length - 1);
  
    var soundSrc = sounds[x];
  
    if (sound) {
        sound.pause();
    } else {
        sound = new Audio();
    }

    sound.src = soundSrc;
    sound.play();
  
    document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = "Now playing: " + soundSrc;
}

document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="soundbutton" class="button button1">Play new song!</a>
<h1 id="song">Not playing anything yet!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a div's `innerHTML` to `soundSrc`:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = soundSrc;

<div id='result'></div>
```